# Prolog Unable to SUM results from forall predicate

Tags: prolog, fibonacci, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to calculate each binomial coeficient in Prolog using the forall predicate.
After I calculate a coeficient I divide it with sqrt(5) and then I would like to sum all the results into a single result, but I am getting an error and I do not know what I need to change in my code in order to work properly.

I use the forLoop predicate to iterate from 0(zero) to N nad the calculateCoeficient predicate for each step.

This is my code:

```
forLoop(Low,High,_,Low):-
    Low=<High.
forLoop(Low,High,Step,Var):-
    Inc is Low+Step, Inc =< High, forLoop(Inc,High,Step,Var).

pow2(X,Y,Z):-Z is X**Y.

permutari(0,1).
permutari(1,1).
permutari(N,R):-N1 is N-1,permutari(N1,R1), R is N*R1.

aranjamente(N,K,R):-permutari(N,R1),N1 is N-K,permutari(N1,R2), R is round(R1/R2).

combinari(N,K,R):-aranjamente(N,K,R1), permutari(K,R2), R is round(R1/R2).

calculateCoeficient(A,B,N,K,R):-
    combinari(N,K,C1), pow2(A,N-K,C2),pow2(B,K,C3), R is C1*C2*C3.


calculateFibo2(N,Step,R,S):-
    Radical is sqrt(5),
    Phi is Radical/2+0.5,
    F1 is float_integer_part(Phi),
    F2 is float_fractional_part(Phi),
    forall(
        forLoop(0,N,Step,K),
        calculateCoeficient(F1,F2,N,K,S),
        R1 is round(S/Radical),
        R := R+R1
    ).
```

For the call: calculateFibo2(2,1,R,S) I get the following exception

```
ERROR: Undefined procedure: forall/4
ERROR:   However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         forall/2
ERROR:         forall/2
ERROR: 
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [9] forall(forLoop(0,2,1,_16156),calculateCoeficient(1.0,0.6180339887498949,2,_16166,_16168),_16172 is round(...),_16182:=_16188+_16190)
ERROR:    [8] calculateFibo2(2,1,_16218,_16220) 
   Exception: (9) forall(forLoop(0, 2, 1, _15580), calculateCoeficient(1.0, 0.6180339887498949, 2, _15580, _15268), _15596 is round(_15268/2.23606797749979), _15266:=_15266+_15596) ?
```

Answer (score 2):

**Just a note that would not fit a comment.**

The de facto standard `forall/2` predicate uses negation in its implementation. It's equivalent to:

```
:- meta_predicate(forall(0, 0)).

forall(Generate, Test) :-
    \+ (Generate, \+ Test).
```

Due to the use of negation, no bindings are returned on a successful call to the `forall/2` predicate. Thus, you cannot use for the computations that you're trying to implement.

P.S. `R := R+R1` should be `R is R+R1`.